# How to replicate records using PLSQL in two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two existing tables and many records already added.

```
formula(formulaId,formulaName,formulaType)
and formula_detail(detailId,formulaId,fieldType,value)
```

Now there is change in formula table and new column is being added , branchId as

```
formula(formulaId,formulaName,formulaType,branchId),

and branch table is branch(branchId,branchName)
```

I want to copy and paste every existing record in formula table for every branch.
e.g if there are 3 existing records in formula table (with ID 1,2,3) and 2 branches. Then copy paste operation should produce total new (3*2)=6 records in formula table and also replicate records in formula_detail table for every newly created formula as follows

for formulaId 1 , If there were 5 records in formula_detail table, then copy paste in formual_detail table will have (2*5) new records added in formual_detail table.

I tried some solutions but number of are records huge and script is taking time. Please help. If need any test code I can add.

Comment: 3*2 = 5? . when did that happen?

Comment: corrected  to 6 !

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result. Also post queries that you tried. It is difficult to understand what exactly do you need from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

First of all replicating same column in detail table is against the Normalized Form used in your Data model.

Still If you want to add the column anyway,

- Add the column using `ALTER` statement in formula_detail table
- Try using this `Merge` statement
  .

  `MERGE INTO formula_detail fd
  USING (SELECT formulaId, branchId from Formula) temp
  ON (fd.formulaId=temp.formulaId)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET fd.branchId=temp.branchId;`

Comment: There is no branchId column in formula_detail

Comment: What do you mean by replicate then?